# Two clients acquiring the same lock in Consul

Tags: go, locking, consul

I have the following code:

```
package publicservice

import (
    "time"
    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api"
    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/testutil"
    "testing"
)

func TestAcquireLock(t *testing.T) {
    consul := testutil.NewTestServer(t)
    defer consul.Stop()

    firstClient, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{
        Address: consul.HTTPAddr,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create first client with %v", err)
    }

    secondClient, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{
        Address: consul.HTTPAddr,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create second client with %v", err)
    }

    lockKey := "sample-lock-key"

    firstLock, err := firstClient.LockOpts(&api.LockOptions{
        Key: lockKey,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create first lock %v", err)
    }

    _, err = firstLock.Lock(nil)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to acquire first lock %v", err)
    }

    defer firstLock.Unlock()

    secondLock, err := secondClient.LockOpts(&api.LockOptions{
        Key: lockKey,
        LockTryOnce: true,
        LockWaitTime: time.Second,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create second lock %v", err)
    }

    _, err = secondLock.Lock(nil)

    if err == nil {
        t.Fatal("should not have acquired lock here")
    }
}
```

And when I run it this second lock call never fails, even if it should fail since the lock is already being held by another client as it can be seen by the logs:

```
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/catalog/nodes (1.115897356s) from=127.0.0.1:50492
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/session/create (939.436µs) from=127.0.0.1:50493
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?wait=15000ms (269.823µs) from=127.0.0.1:50493
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?acquire=aa8fb351-6b6e-8e17-f8d9-fb265c497a9f&flags=3304740253564472344 (899.564µs) from=127.0.0.1:50493
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?consistent= (112.87µs) from=127.0.0.1:50493
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/session/create (595.554µs) from=127.0.0.1:50494
2016/11/29 14:46:25 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?wait=1000ms (38.602µs) from=127.0.0.1:50494
2016/11/29 14:46:26 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?index=7&wait=999ms (1.007117154s) from=127.0.0.1:50494
2016/11/29 14:46:26 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/session/destroy/fd83b8f8-1757-d9d7-6f0e-5defaf26b886 (1.549558ms) from=127.0.0.1:50494
2016/11/29 14:46:26 [DEBUG] http: Request PUT /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?flags=3304740253564472344&release=aa8fb351-6b6e-8e17-f8d9-fb265c497a9f (1.56451ms) from=127.0.0.1:50495
2016/11/29 14:46:26 [DEBUG] http: Request GET /v1/kv/sample-lock-key?consistent=&index=7 (1.010637359s) from=127.0.0.1:50493
```

What am I missing here? Is there something else I must do to make sure the second client doesn't acquire the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that you have to check the channel that's returned from `Lock`, if the lock is already held the channel is `nil`:

```
package publicservice

import (
    "time"
    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/api"
    "github.com/hashicorp/consul/testutil"
    "testing"
    "github.com/xtgo/uuid"
)

func TestAcquireLock(t *testing.T) {
    consul := testutil.NewTestServer(t)
    defer consul.Stop()

    firstClient, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{
        Address: consul.HTTPAddr,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create first client with %v", err)
    }

    secondClient, err := api.NewClient(&api.Config{
        Address: consul.HTTPAddr,
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create second client with %v", err)
    }

    lockKey := "sample-lock-key"

    firstLock, err := firstClient.LockOpts(&api.LockOptions{
        Key: lockKey,
        SessionName: uuid.NewRandom().String(),
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create first lock %v", err)
    }

    firstResult, err := firstLock.Lock(nil)

    t.Logf("=====> result for first lock is %v", firstResult)

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to acquire first lock %v", err)
    }

    defer firstLock.Unlock()

    secondLock, err := secondClient.LockOpts(&api.LockOptions{
        Key: lockKey,
        LockTryOnce: true,
        LockWaitTime: time.Second,
        SessionName: uuid.NewRandom().String(),
    })

    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to create second lock %v", err)
    }

    secondResult, err := secondLock.Lock(nil)

    if secondResult != nil || err != nil {
        t.Fatal("should not have acquired lock here")
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this question is old but i just recently found out about it. anyways, im just curious what is the logic behind checking secondResult to be nil.  .Lock() blocks so I assumed that whenever it unblocked, you can assume that it obtained the lock. The fact that you're saying you need to check for secondResult to be not nil suggests to me that .Lock() doesn't actually block?

Comment: It doesn't, it's not supposed to, you check the result only to know if you actually did acquire the lock or not.